# keydown not firing on div

Tags: jquery, switch-statement, keydown

I'm having issues with my keydown. When the page is on the div "screenA" the user has two options, press space or "i" key. The "i" key shows an alert, and the space bar shows the div `screenTimer` . When the user is on the div `screenTimer` she should be able to press the right arrow key to call up `startTesting()` and also a console log.

The i key and space bar work, but the right arrow key (39) does nothing, and doesn't display the console log either.

```
$(document).keydown( function(e)
            {
                if ( boolKeyDepressed )
                    return;
                else
                    boolKeyDepressed = true;

        var e = e || window.event;
                var ltr = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
                var trans = "";


                if ( ltr == 13 ) 
                {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }

                switch(ltr)
                {

                    case 73: // "i" key

                        if (!$('screenA').is(':visible')) {
                        alert("i key");
                        }   
                        break;
                    case 32: // space bar 

                        if (!$('screenA').is(':visible')) {

                        showDiv('screenTimer');
                        hideDiv("screenA");

                        }

                        break;

                    case 39: // right arrow key

                        if (!$('screenTimer').is(':visible')) {
                     console.log("timer");
                        startTesting();
                    }

                        break;


                }


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

U have to use keypress not keydown, try your code with keypress

Comment: it's still not working =\ only the first two cases work, the i key and space bar. once i get to screenTimer, the right arrow key doesn't fire

Comment: where is the startTesting() function, you have it right

Comment: Also try e.which instead of e.keycode, e.which works on all browsers